# How to exit an iAd Interstitial in IOS Application (Spritekit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad

I'm using sprite kit to write my app and I'm using iAd for my ads. I have used the current code to implement a fullscreen ad:

```
interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
interstitial.delegate = self;
CGRect interstitialFrame = self.frame;
UIView *adView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:interstitialFrame];
[view addSubview:adView];
[interstitial presentInView:adView];
```

and this is in my GameScene.m class. It works and it shows a fullscreen ad and it's the only implementation of Interstitial ads that I've got working so far.

When I run the application it shows a fullscreen ad (which is what I want) but there is no exit button? Im not sure if this changes when the actual app gets published to the app store?

So my questions are...

1. How do I create an exit button for the ad?
2. How do I make it "go away" completely and properly and still be able to create a new one later on?
3. And also is this is the most effective and efficient way of creating Interstitial iAds?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating the view for showing the inerstitial on your own?

Use

> ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Automatic

to leverage the build in logic of the iAd Framework. This will also add an exit button to the ad,

Here's a SWIFT version of my sample code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initialize the Ad
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

}

func showAd() {
    self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Automatic
}
```

The complete tutorial can be found here: [Quick Tip: Implement fullscreen (interstitial) Ads for iOS in SWIFT](http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.de/2015/06/interstitial-ads.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude! Im using sprite kit and objective-c is there a version for that. I have trouble interpreting swift code and also where do I need to put this code? Kind regards, Ryan

Comment: I guess it is quite similar. Something like: [UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds]; in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: Im getting an error, would you mind creating a new sprite kit project in Xcode and see if it works for you? I would really appreciate it and I will be happy to pay you for your time if necessary :)